# spree error message in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree

I am new to ruby on rails. I installed ruby and gems both on my ubuntu 10.10 system. My rails -v is 3.0.5 and gem -v is 1.3.7. As my requirement I installed bundler and after that when I installed spree by the command  `gem install spree`  I got the following error message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing spree:
    spree_core requires will_paginate (= 3.0.pre2, runtime)
```

I googled many hours but didn't find any good result. So please help me.I am really a newbie in Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
gem update --system
gem install will_paginate -v=3.0.pre2 --pre
gem install spree
```

You tell it manually to install the correct required version of will_paginate. Maybe that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Ya I tried your code but still getting the  same error ERROR:  Error installing spree:
 spree_core requires will_paginate (= 3.0.pre2, runtime)

Comment: Try running __gem update --system__, then run the code again.

Answer (score 0):

This should all work through bundler. Have you added the spree gem to your **Gemfile** and run `bundle install`? Are you using RVM? Post the results of `bundle list` and `rvm info`(if applicable) if you're still having problems